# Issue applying theme to Application

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to apply a theme to my entire android application, which for now only changes the looks of all the buttons in the app.  Currently I have no errors, and the app will launch in my virtual machine(I'm using eclipse).  My problem is that despite not having any errors, the theme is not applied to the app.  Here's how I have everything set up:

res/color/custom_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/yellow1"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/orange4"
                android:startColor="@color/orange5"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/white1"
                android:startColor="@color/white2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources >
      <style name="PurdueButtons" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
          <item name="android:background">@color/custom_button</item>
      </style>
      <style name="PurdueTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
          <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/PurdueButtons</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

Relative line from AndroidManifest:

```
android:theme="@style/PurdueTheme" >
```

All of my colors are defined in res/values/colors.xml, and I know I have this set up correctly.  Eclipse seems to have no problem locating everything, so I am confused as to why the theme, mainly the changes I have made to the buttons, is not being applied.

Comment: Could you post screenshots on what it should look like and what it does look like?

Comment: android:theme="@styles/PurdueTheme" >  is in the application section, so I know I put this in the correct place

Comment: @hichris123, right now it is displaying the default holo dark theme for the buttons, so they are black.  As you can see in the custom_button.xml code above, the buttons are supposed to be white in there default state